# Rails, Count of Users Grouped by created_at day - PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am using Rails 5, PostgreSQL. I need to get count of users grouped by created_at day, using postgres DATE_TRUNC. 
The conditions are users created within a date range and have orders within the same date range.

Below is my code which result in an AmbiguousFunction error

```
Spree::User.joins(:orders)
           .where(spree_orders: { completed_at: params[:start_date]..params[:end_date] })
           .order("DATE_TRUNC('day', 'created_at')")
           .group("DATE_TRUNC('day', 'created_at')")
           .count
```

The params of start_date and end_date are as follow:

```
params[:end_date] = Time.current.end_of_day
params[:start_date] = (Time.current - 200.days).beginning_of_day
```

I get the following error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousFunction: ERROR:  function date_trunc(unknown, unknown) is not unique

and even when I explicitly write spree_users.created_at  I get the same error.

Is there a better way to achieve the required or a solution for this error?

Comment: I don't use PostgreSQL but either you shouldn't wrap `created_at` in quotes and/or the column is ambiguous; try `users.created_at` (no single quotes).

Comment: Not meant to answer the question but `order("DATE_TRUNC('day', 'created_at')")` should be superfluous because of the grouping and counting.

Comment: @M.Wyatt tried it and still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousFunction

This error occurs when our query contains a column name, which may belong to more than one table. For example, we have two tables, `User` and `Company`, and both of them have a column called `name`. Now the following query would raise an error similar to the one that you are facing:

```
User.joins(:companies).where("name = ABC")
```

This happens because we do not specify which table to search the `name` in. Hence, `ActiveRecord` gets confused and cannot create a unique query.
In the case mentioned above, the error can be resolved simply by prepending `spree_users` to the `created_at` column name used in the `order` and `group` queries:

```
Spree::User.joins(:orders)
       .where(spree_orders: { completed_at: params[:start_date]..params[:end_date] })
       .order("DATE_TRUNC('day', 'spree_users.created_at')")
       .group("DATE_TRUNC('day', 'spree_users.created_at')")
       .count
```

Comment: Thanks alot, adding 'spree_users.created_at' this removed  removed AmbiguousFunction error. There was another error due to default scope sorting conflicting with order by date here so adding unscope(;order) solved the 2nd issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use date function from sql to get date of timestamp field, and since table User and SpreeOrder has created_at field, you should inform table name (spree_orders.created_at)

```
Spree::User.joins(:orders)
  .where(spree_orders: { completed_at: params[:start_date]..params[:end_date]})
  .order("date(spree_orders.created_at)")
  .group("date(spree_orders.created_at)")
  .count
```